# Are there any objective reasons to prefer a template based paradigm to a function based paradigm for markup?

Tags: javascript, html, templates, architecture, frameworks

Most existing web frameworks use a template paradigm for markup. You write what looks mostly like HTML, but there are all sorts of DSL add-ons, such as custom HTML attributes that the framework hooks into when managing control flow, placeholder syntax for dynamic content, and so on.

Here are some examples of popular template approaches:

[Django templates](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/templates/):

```
{% extends "base_generic.html" %}

{% block title %}{{ section.title }}{% endblock %}

{% block content %}
<h1>{{ section.title }}</h1>

{% for story in story_list %}
<h2>
  <a href="{{ story.get_absolute_url }}">
    {{ story.headline|upper }}
  </a>
</h2>
<p>{{ story.tease|truncatewords:"100" }}</p>
{% endfor %}
{% endblock %}
```

[Vue templates](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/syntax.html):

```
<div v-bind:id="dynamicId">
  <!--This markup will be the template of the root instance-->
  <h1 v-if="seen">My Vue.js App</h1>
  <p> {{ message.split('').reverse().join('') }}</p>
  <NonStandardMarkupIsFineHere/>
</div>
```

[Angular templates](https://angular.io/guide/template-syntax):

```
<button (click)="onSave($event)">Save</button>
<button *ngFor="let hero of heroes" (click)="deleteHero(hero)">
  {{hero.name}}
</button>
<form #heroForm (ngSubmit)="onSubmit(heroForm)"> ... </form>
```

In contrast, frameworks like React, Cycle, or the Elm architecture use a function based paradigm. You call functions that update the DOM or an intermediary virtual DOM directly.

Here are some examples:

[Cycle.js](https://cycle.js.org/getting-started.html#getting-started-coding-consider-jsx):

```
  const sinks = {
    DOM: sources.DOM.select('input').events('click')
      .map(ev => ev.target.checked)
      .startWith(false)
      .map(toggled =>
        div([
          input({attrs: {type: 'checkbox'}}), 'Toggle me',
          p(toggled ? 'ON' : 'off')
        ])
      )
  }
```

[React.js:](https://reactjs.org/docs/jsx-in-depth.html)

```
const Button = props => {
  const { kind, ...other } = props;
  const className = kind === "primary" ? "PrimaryButton" : "SecondaryButton";
  return <button className={className} {...other} />;
};

const App = () => {
  return (
    <div>
      <Button kind="primary" onClick={() => console.log("clicked!")}>
        Hello World!
      </Button>
    </div>
  );
};
```

When choosing between frameworks, this is often a deciding factor.

**My question is: is there any objective reason to prefer one to another, or does this difference amount to mere subjective preference?** Are there common use cases that are better suited to template language systems, that would be substantially more difficult to write or reason about than a function based system?

For example, something I could see being proposed is that template systems are "just HTML", so they are simpler and more familiar. However, this is not true. They are not just HTML, they are html extended by DSL concepts at every turn. The markup is full of logic, only it is written in the form of strings and other non-html constructs. Also, many function based paradigms offer syntactic sugar such as JSX that bring the appearance as close to html as most template languages.

Answer (score 0):

The idea is that the closer a template system is to the resulting output, the more it is a "template", and not an application.  A template by it's very definition resembles the finished product as much as possible.  This helps people achieve a cognitive bridge between the code they are writing, and the resulting HTML.

The farther this gap, the more abstract cognitive thinking is needed to understand the resulting HTML.  This may be easy for some, and more difficult for others, but it is still a cognitive load that should not be discounted out of hand.

It's the same reason we use high level languages instead of low level ones.  It reduces the cognitive load on software developers so that they can focus on meeting the goals of the application.